# jquery error when split

Tags: jquery, html, json

I've got an error when I split for checkbox.

```js
var ukuran = data['model'].ukuran_model;
var cek = ukuran.split(",").join('], [value='),
  $inputs = $('input[name^=ukuran]');
$inputs.filter('[value=' + cek + ']').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="XS">XL</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="S">S</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="M">M</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="L">L</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="XL">XL</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="2L">2L</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="3L">3L</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="4L">4L</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="5L">5L</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="Small">Small</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="BigSize">BigSize</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="ExtraBig">ExtraBig</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="5/6">5/6</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="7/8">7/8</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="9/10">9/10</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="11/12">11/12</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="SS">SS</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="S/M">S/M</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 ukuran">
    <input class="ukuran_input" type="checkbox" name="ukuran[]" value="L/XL">L/XL</div>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

This is the data from the JSON response:

```js
{
    "bahan": [{
        "id_bahan": "6",
        "nm_bahan": "Combed Sakura",
        "stok_bahan": "3",
        "nm_jenis": "Katun Sp 08",
        "nm_warna": "merah",
        "no": 1
    }, {
        "id_bahan": "3",
        "nm_bahan": "Bhn Jaket 02",
        "stok_bahan": "3",
        "nm_jenis": "Katun Sp 08",
        "nm_warna": "hijau",
        "no": 2
    }],
    "model": {
        "id_model": "4",
        "nm_model": "Zn 225 W",
        "ukuran_model": "XS,S,M,L,XL,2L,3L,4L,5L,Small,BigSize,ExtraBig,5\/6,7\/8,9\/10,11\/12,SS,S\/M,L\/XL",
        "foto_model1": "9_Cardigan-Muslimah-Zenitha-Modis-DAyw7Gafw.jpg",
        "foto_model2": "",
        "foto_model3": "",
        "keterangan_model": "cddcscs"
    },
    "detail": [{
        "id_detail": "8"
    }, {
        "id_detail": "7"
    }]
}
```

its show error in google chrome development (`concole.log()`), this say error :

> jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value=XS], [value=S], [value=M], [value=L], [value=XL], [value=2L], [value=3L], [value=4L], [value=5L], [value=Small], [value=BigSize], [value=ExtraBig], [value=5/6], [value=7/8], [value=9/10], [value=11/12], [value=SS], [value=S/M], [value=L/XL]

How can I fix it? So far so good when I input checkbox just four checkbox. But, when i input many checkbox, i've error !

Comment: You mean 

`$inputs.filter(cek).prop('checked', true);`

Comment: Try adding double quotes for each value here join('], [value=" '), and  filter('[value="'

Comment: i change with `$inputs.filter(cek).prop('checked', true);` .but it same error guys

Comment: If it works with four (XS/S/M/L ?) then why not add 1 at a time until you get the error, then you'll see *which one* causes the error - most likely it's with `/`

Comment: That `prop('checked', true)` comment should have been marked "off topic" or "aside" (or similar) - it's not an answer to your issue, it's an observeration on your code.

Comment: As an alternative, why not use the class to get the inputs?  `$inputs = $(".ukuran>input")` or `$inputs = $(".ukuran_input")` ?

Comment: oh, i will try freedomn-m . its good suggestion, don't left me when i've done try your suggest...

Comment: @freedomn-m i've been try your suggest. its okay when i check `XS,S,M,L,XL,2L,3L,4L,5L,Small,BigSize,ExtraBig` but, when i check the next `5/6` i got error.. how i should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add doble quotes. find fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1b3jtLof/5/)

```
var ukuran = 'XL,S,M,L';
var cek = ukuran.split(",").join('"], [value="');
var inputs = $('input[name^=ukuran]');
inputs.filter('[value="' + cek + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```